# how to depoly rails4.2 app in apache2.2 in windows? using mongrel or thin databse is oracle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apache2.2

i installed apache 2.2 and thin gem i done configeration

```
ServerAdmin serveradmin.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Sites/Autopk/public/"
ServerName servername.com
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/thin_error.log"
#LogLevel debug
CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/thin_access.log" common
<Directory "C:/Sites/Autopk/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <Files *.xml>
         ForceType application/vnd.ms-excel
         Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
</Directory>
#RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine   on
# Pass all non-PHP, non-static-file requests to the Mongrel server on port 3000
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     (.*) http://localhost:3000$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

please help me ? and how can iknpn i know is apche is configure with rails?

Comment: Can you please reformat your code snippet? I'm afraid it is a bit unclear as it is.

Comment: ok sure i will do it

Comment: i done please check it